# Am I understanding something wrong about randomization?

Tags: r, testing, random, p-value

I thought randomization 'equalizes all factors (whether observed or not)' between the treatment group and control group.

To test this, I have performed the code below, and found out that in more than half of the cases randomization did not work well - meaning at least one variable was statistically different between randomly split treatment group and control group.

```
set.seed(1234)
for (i in 1:1000){
  
  ind<-sample(2, 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
  
  a<-as.matrix(rnorm(10000, mean=0, sd=1))
  b<-as.matrix(rnorm(10000, mean=0.5, sd=1)) 
  c<-as.matrix(rnorm(10000, mean=1, sd=2))
  dt<-data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
  dt$X4 <- dt$X1 + dt$X2
  dt$X5 <- dt$X1 * dt$X3
  
  dt1<-dt[ind==1,]
  dt2<-dt[ind==2,]
  
  a_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[1,], dt2[1,])$p.value
  b_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[2,], dt2[2,])$p.value
  c_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[3,], dt2[3,])$p.value
  d_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[4,], dt2[4,])$p.value
  e_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[5,], dt2[5,])$p.value
}

pval<-data.frame(cbind(a_pval,b_pval,c_pval,d_pval,e_pval))

pval<-mutate(pval, adiff = ifelse(a_pval<0.05, 1,0))
pval<-mutate(pval, bdiff = ifelse(b_pval<0.05, 1,0))
pval<-mutate(pval, cdiff = ifelse(c_pval<0.05, 1,0))
pval<-mutate(pval, ddiff = ifelse(d_pval<0.05, 1,0))
pval<-mutate(pval, ediff = ifelse(e_pval<0.05, 1,0))
pval$diff<-pval$adiff+pval$bdiff+pval$cdiff+pval$ddiff+pval$ediff

table(pval$diff)

length(which(a_pval<0.05))
length(which(b_pval<0.05))
length(which(c_pval<0.05))
length(which(d_pval<0.05))
length(which(e_pval<0.05))
```

Is it because there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: why the `set.seed()`? It wil create reproducible results (i.e.: not random)

Comment: @Wimpel, the results are pseudo-random, as they almost always are in R.  There are ways to get true random values (see the `random` package) but almost nobody uses them because they are very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the tests are doing what you think they're doing.  Your t tests are working on rows of your matrices, not columns, so the distribution isn't normal, it's a degenerate mixture of normals.  Change the t test lines to

```
a_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[,1], dt2[,1])$p.value
b_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[,2], dt2[,2])$p.value
c_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[,3], dt2[,3])$p.value
d_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[,4], dt2[,4])$p.value
e_pval[i]<-t.test(dt1[,5], dt2[,5])$p.value
```

and that will be fixed, and you'll see that about 5% of your p-values are less than 0.05, as expected.

I honestly don't understand what you were expecting to see in the `pval$diff` table.  Since columns 4 and 5 are based on the first 3 columns, the columns are dependent, and you shouldn't expect to see a standard distribution of counts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Changed lines worked and it returned the results I was expecting. ```pval$diff``` table was to see the probability of getting 'well balanced random split(meaning p-values are expected to be big enough in all 5 variables) '.